# Generate N random numbers using randomR

Tags: haskell, random

I want to generate N random numbers between a range using randomR.

I know there are other ways to accomplish this such as using `randomRs` and taking N as in this code which can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/24):

```
diff_select :: Int -> Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
diff_select n m = take n . nub . randomRs (1, m)
```

but I want to do it using **`randomR`** and using a `State` monad. I am not sure where I am erring with this code:

```
let fs = \s -> (randomR (0, 5) s, s)
let theState s = state (fs s)
let rep n ma = replicateM n (theState ma)
let res = runState (rep 3) (mkStdGen 4) -- Would like to use `get`
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What error message are you getting?  I know you're going to be getting one, but you should always post any error associated with your code when asking a question.

Comment: More than the error, since I think my approach isn't correct, I just want to know how to accomplish what I am pretending to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `State` monad to generate random numbers, you want your state value to be the generator.  In this case, we can just use `StdGen`:

```
type RandGen a = State StdGen a
```

Then you can write you function for generating a single random value

```
getRandom :: Random a => RandGen a
getRandom = do
    gen <- get
    let (val, newGen) = random gen
    put newGen
    return val
```

Now you can use this to generate multiple random numbers using all the usual `Monad` functions, like `sequence`, `mapM`, etc.  I'll let you implement this part.  Finally, all you have to do is execute the code:

```
> runState getRandom (mkStdGen 42) :: (Int, StdGen)
```

---

If you want to make it even easier, the `state` function has the following type:

```
state :: MonadState s m => (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
```

And `random` has the type

```
random :: (Random a, RandomGen g) => g -> (a, g)
```

Notice how `s` and `g` seem to line up here?  You can actually replace `getRandom` by

```
getRandom :: Random a => RandGen a
getRandom = state random
```

And all of the hard work is done for you.

Comment: Not answering the question: "I want to do it using *randomR* and [...]"

Comment: Ok, so how could you write something very, very similar to what I have using `randomR`?  What is the type of `randomR`?

Comment: To put it another way, I could define a `getRandomR` that is a total of 2 non-whitespace characters different from `getRandom` that would solve your problem.  The purpose of my answer was not to just give you the full solution, but give you a framework for solving it yourself ;)

Comment: Sorry, but that won't do, I mean, I still don't understand, although I think I am close. I tried: `let rep n a b = replicateM n (state (randomR (a, b)))` and then `get (runState (rep 3 1 6))` but I am missing something.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion I think you're misunderstanding how to use the state monad in general, not how to generate random numbers with it.  The `get` function only works inside of `runState`, `runState` turns a `State s a` value and an initial `s` value into a `(a, s)` value.

Comment: I had omitted the initial state... `runState (rep 3 1 6)) (mkStdGen 98453)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
let res = runState (rep 3) (mkStdGen 4)
```

What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
runState (rep 3 (mkStdGen 4))
```

... which is not the same thng.

Comment: Isn't working. Says: Couldn't match type `t0 -> m0 [(a0, s0)]'
              with `StateT StdGen Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a'. Edited to correct that mistake. But still isn't working.